# Cocos2D-x Enable CCMenuItemSprite by tag c++

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

Is it possible to enable or disable a CCMenuItemSprite by it's tag?

example:

```
itemSprite(tag)->setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose **menu** is the parent of your item (probably object of CCMenu class) and **tag** is your tag, you can do something like this:

```
CCNode *itemSprite = menu->getChildByTag(tag);
itemSprite->setEnabled(false);
```